# getElementsByClassName does not return a fixed answer

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

In Javascript, I get the elements of a given class using:

```
A = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
> A contains elements e1, e2, e3, e4
```

Then, I change the class of one of these elements:

```
document.getElementById("e2").className = "anotherclass";
```

To my great surprise, the array A has been automatically changed in the process !!

```
> A contains elements e1, e3, e4
```

I thought that the array returned by `getElementsByClassName` would stay the same now that is was assigned.

- How is that possible? Is it an intended behaviour?
- Is there a simple way to change that?

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USmsH/1/).

Note that this is also true for `getElementById`.

Comment: FYI, if you don't want the returned `nodeList` to be live (as the answers have explained), you can switch to using `document.querySelectorAll()` which returns a static `nodeList` and has better browser support than `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 - But wouldn't changing the class still be updated in the non-live nodelist. I answered the same thing, but then tested it **http://jsfiddle.net/USmsH/2/**, and it seems a non-live nodelist is only static to the extent of actual DOM changes, as in adding/removing children etc.

Comment: @adeneo: Your demo shows all four elements in the list (testing in Firefox).

Comment: @adeneo - A non-live nodeList is nothing more than a static list of nodes.  It will not change.  See the console in here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nDkga/

Comment: Of course it shows all four elements in the console, but if you look at the question the OP is changing the class, and it's updated in the live nodeList, but that happens in a non-live nodeList as well. The console shows all four elements, and the class on the second one *is* changed. If you add or remove elements, that would be an actual change to the DOM structure, which is not reflected in the non-live nodeList, hence my comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `A` is not an `Array`. `getElementByClassName` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is live-updated due to changes in the document.

The easiest way to convert an array-like object into an array would be to do this:

```
var A = ...

// With ES5 code
var A_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(A);

// With ES6 code
var A_array = Array.from(A);
```

Or you can get `NodeList` instead via `querySelectorAll`, which won't live-update.

```
var A = document.querySelectorAll('.someclass');
```

Comment: Actually, I think the easiest way would be to use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ha, yes good point.

Answer (score 1):

These functions return *live* NodeLists. This means that they are automatically updated to reflect the current contents of the DOM.

See the [`NodeList` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: Not all `nodeList`s are live.  `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a non-live `nodeList`.  You have to consult the specific function to see whether it returns a live or non-live `nodeList`.

Comment: I know that. It says it in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: My point was that you have to refer to the doc for the function you're using, not the `nodeList` doc to know whether your `nodeList` is live or not.  In this case, the doc for `getElementsByClassName()` would have been more relevant in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm, MDN documentation of getElementsByClassName doesn't mention that it's a live NodeList. w3fools doesn't mention it, either, but I wouldn't link to them even if they did. Got a better reference that I can add to my answer?

Comment: That's a miss that the MDN doc doesn't explain it.  I don't have a better MDN-style reference.